# Adding files from specific locations and adding them to listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I would like to code a function to which opens a file location, for eg. `C:\Users\User` from which I can add an MP3 file, and add it to `listbox`. I've tried this  but it doesn't open the folder i want. Any ideas?

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
    paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work **excactly**? does there any error appear? are the values you get into the `ListBox` the wrong ones? what do you mean with *it doesn't open the folder i want*?? What folder do you wanna (get) open?

Comment: I've not tried multiple file selections but for one file i used openFileDialog1.SelectedFile to get the file the user picked

Answer (score 2):

set the initial directory:

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\User";
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `InitialDirectory` property of the `OpenFileDialog`, will set the start up folder.